# Puppeteer Page.setDownloadBehavior dont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to download a file using puppeteer with `setDownloadBehavior`, but it's not working, the code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

async function teste(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
  });

  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  await page.type("[name='user[email]']", process.env.EMAIL);
  await page.type("[name='user[password]']", process.env.PASS);

  await page.click("[type='submit']");

  await page.waitForSelector(".mdi.mdi-bell.noti-icon");

  const downloadPath = path.resolve(__dirname + "./");
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
    behavior: "allow",
    downloadPath: downloadPath,
  });

  await page.goto(process.env.URL_DOC);
  await delay(3);

  await page.click('input[name="commit"]');
  await delay(2);
  await page.click("button.btn.btn-secondary.btn-no-print"); // button to download the file

  console.log("Done");

  browser.close();
}

function delay(n) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, n * 1000);
  });
}
```

The code always stops executing here:

[image]